# Jmeter unable to pass + in the email id

Tags: jmeter

In the variable 'aaa+test01@gmail.com' in my jmeter request, + is not be send to jmeter, in the view results i am seeing aaatest01@gmail.com, how to handle this.

Trying to create a JMeter test for registration to a site where my username is my email. I've tried with encode checked and unchecked but it keeps coming back saying invalid login, and in the HTTP request i see it not posting the variable with + symbol. Any suggestions on what i'm doing wrong?
eg: User name : aaa+test01@gmail.com 
Thanks & Regards,
Srikar

Comment: It should work, can you should the HTTP request and Test Plan variable?

Answer (score 1):

In general if you record your request using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) JMeter should populate a "good" HTTP Request sampler configuration.

Alternatively there are 2 options on how you can proceed. Given you have `somevar` JMeter Variable with the value of `aaa+test01@gmail.com`

1. Tick `Encode?` box for the relevant parameter in the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

   [image: JMeter Encode Parameter]
2. Wrap your variable in [__urlEncode() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode) like `${__urlencode(${somevar})}` if for some reason point 1 is not applicable for your scenario.

   [image: JMeter UrlEncode]

   See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) to learn more about JMeter Functions concept.